# How to compile mysql-server example plugins

Tags: mysql, plugins, cmake

I want to write a information schema plugin for mysql,and first Im trying to compile the example plugins and have some errors.
The CmakeList.txt is this:

```
MYSQL_ADD_PLUGIN(daemon_example daemon_example.cc
MODULE_ONLY TEST_ONLY MODULE_OUTPUT_NAME "libdaemon_example")

INSTALL(FILES daemon_example.ini DESTINATION ${INSTALL_PLUGINDIR} COMPONENT Test)
```

It is said Unknown Cmake command "MYSQL_ADD_PLUGIN",

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 6.1.7601.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.11.25547.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.11.25547.0
Check for working C compiler: E:/visual studio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: E:/visual studio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: E:/visual studio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: E:/visual studio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (MYSQL_ADD_PLUGIN):
  Unknown CMake command "MYSQL_ADD_PLUGIN".


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
```

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

```
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I found this function is in mysql-server\cmake file,

```
MACRO(MYSQL_ADD_PLUGIN)
MYSQL_PARSE_ARGUMENTS(ARG
"LINK_LIBRARIES;DEPENDENCIES;MODULE_OUTPUT_NAME;STATIC_OUTPUT_NAME"
"STORAGE_ENGINE;STATIC_ONLY;MODULE_ONLY;CLIENT_ONLY;MANDATORY;DEFAULT;DISABLED;NOT_FOR_EMBEDDED;RECOMPILE_FOR_EMBEDDED;TEST_ONLY"
${ARGN}
)
```

I wonder how to fix it and make the compile success?
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Ran.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow we wants error message to be included into the question post **as text**, not linked as image. Please, [edit] your question post and paste text of the error message into it. You may format this text with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: I am not expert with MySQL plugin, but absence of line with `cmake_minimum_required` in `CMakeLists.txt` usually signals, that this script **isn't standalone** - you should run `cmake` from some other directory. Probably, you should place your `CMakeLists.txt` and other plugin files into some subdirectory of the main project (MySQL in your case), and then run `cmake` for that project. You script will be processed as a part of the whole project, when all needed macros will be defined. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any specific info about this process for MySQL plugins.